# Is there any maximum number of columns in a Grid? How to change it?

Tags: wpf, gridview

I'm using a WPF Grid with DevXpress GridControl and apparently I can't show more than 31 columns. Is it possible?

If so, is there any way to surpass that limit?

Comment: Did it occur to you to ask DevExpress? You use a commercial product that COMES WITH GREAT SUPPORT ;) Just implying. This is a question I would hit their support with.

Comment: Thanks, I checked their support forum where they said is virtually unlimited so I supposed it was a Grid's limitation as I'm using DX GridControl on a non-DX Grid. Maybe weird but It's been fine till now